# Show tick labels on both edges in groupplot

Tags: pgfplots, labels, groupplots

I would like to put quite many small plots in a `groupplot` environment and provide ticklabels on all adges of the groupplot (no labels at individual plots).
In the following example, I've set the labels to bottom and left. I could set them to top and right, too, but I am looking for an option called "both" or the like and could not find it. How can I print the labels on all four edges?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 2,
        horizontal sep=7pt,vertical sep=7pt,
        xticklabels at=edge bottom,
        yticklabels at=edge left},
    axis on top,
    enlargelimits=false,
    xmin=-26,xmax=26,ymin=-2,ymax=2,
    height=5cm,width=.4\textwidth]
    \nextgroupplot[]
    \addplot {sin(x)};
    \nextgroupplot[]
    \addplot {sin(x)};
    \nextgroupplot[]
    \addplot {sin(x)};
    \nextgroupplot[]
    \addplot {sin(x)};
    \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 2):

A bit more tedious, but you can set the `ticklabel pos` for each axis:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 2,
        horizontal sep=7pt,vertical sep=7pt},
    axis on top,
    enlargelimits=false,
    xmin=-26,xmax=26,ymin=-2,ymax=2,
    height=5cm,width=.4\textwidth]
    \nextgroupplot[xticklabel pos=right]
    \addplot {sin(x)};
    \nextgroupplot[xticklabel pos=right,yticklabel pos=right]
    \addplot {sin(x)};
    \nextgroupplot[]
    \addplot {sin(x)};
    \nextgroupplot[yticklabel pos=right]
    \addplot {sin(x)};
    \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! Of course, manual positioning is a way, but if possible, I would to have some automated solution since there will be quite a few groupplots with many elements each.

Comment: This example does not work for me. In particular, "yticklabel pos=right" has no effect. In a 2x2 group plot, I also want to show y tick labels on the outer edges. However, I only see the y tick labels on the left 2 sub-plots, no y tick labels are shown on the right 2 sub-plots. Can someone continue to help?

Comment: Sorry, I tried this example again. This example worked this time. The reason I failed the first time is that "y descriptions at" conflict with "yticklabels pos". Namely, if I used "y descriptions at=edge left", then  "yticklabels pos=right" stops working.